# Using tail -f together with sed and xargs

Tags: sed, xargs, tail

Suppose I have the following process to write a number + single quote to the file `/tmp/test` every second:

```
for i in {1..1000} ; do echo $i\' ; sleep 1 ; done > /tmp/test
```

I then want to use `tail -f` and run this through another function. For testing purposes, I'm using `echo`:

```
tail -f /tmp/test | xargs echo
```

This give me the following error (running this without a quote in the input works fine):

`xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option`

If I add sed to the equation, I don't get any output at all:

```
tail -f /tmp/test | sed "s/['\"]//g" | xargs echo
```

Any ideas why I get no output after adding `sed`, or another way how I can strip the quotes from the input before it gets to `xargs`?

Comment: And what arguments would you like be passed to `echo`? Each blank-delimited word in the input (quotes not special, how about backslash?)? Or the full content of each line?

Comment: My actual xargs command is `xargs -0 -n1 -d '\n' -I {} bash -c 'log -e "$@"' _ {}` which seems to be working now after adding the -d parameter

Comment: `-0`, `-n1` (or `-I`) and `bash` are superfluous here. `xargs -rd '\n' -n1 log -e`

Comment: unfortunately not, log is a function that is otherwise not recognized, try yourself: `log() { echo $1; } ; export -f log ; echo test| xargs -rd '\n' -n1 log`

Comment: Oh exported bash function I take it. Then `xargs -rd '\n' -n1 bash -c 'log "$@"' bash` (avoid `_` for `$0`). But instead of running one `bash` per line, you may want to use a `while IFS= read -r line` loop within **one** bash instance and do away with `xargs`.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas that is a much better solution indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of things.

First: "tail -f" will never finish, so "xargs" will likewise remain running indefinitely. You can open a second window to "kill -HUP" the "tail -f" process to make both the "tail -f" and "xargs" finish, and thus produce output.

Second: "xargs" is buffering the input, and not getting what it considers to be a "full buffer", so by the time the 1000 second marks have been output, it hasn't yet run the echo command even once. If you'd like "xargs" to run the echo separately for each input row, you'd need to add "-n 1" option to xargs.

As for "xargs" not liking the single quote marks, you could use option "-d '\n'" to disable the quote processing and only separate the input arguments by a newline.

Comment: Thanks! Adding '\n' solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
tail -f /tmp/test | sed "s/['\"]//g" | while read line; do
  do_something "$line"
done
```

And check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199266/make-xargs-execute-the-command-once-for-each-line-of-input